# How can I show a text in a progressbar?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, progress-bar

I created a progressbar, and I like to display some text in it. Maybe a percentage or remaining time, or something like this. How can I do that using pure Win32 api?

Comment: Reading though [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760818%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it doesn't seem to be possible with the standard progress bar control.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I know, I didn`t find anything usefull either. But it should be possible, because Installers can display the percentage, and a lot of things displays a text in a progressbar. I just don't know how.

Comment: Then they probably make their own progress bar controls.

Comment: I'd write my own control and paint both progress and text.  The theme API lets you paint the progress adhering to the prevailing theme.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/859491/Cplusplus-MFC-ProgressBar-with-Percentage-Overlay) you find a sample how to do it.

Even if this is MFC code, you can see the way how to write your own window with your own handler and WM_PAINT code.